# Swift 3 conversion emcompassing muliple issues

Tags: swift3

I have started converting to swift 3 while removing **NS** classes as much as possible, but ran into a snag with his code:

```
var S: String = ADataItem.description_text;
// FRegExBufui_Image is of type NSRegularExpression
let matches: [NSTextCheckingResult] = FRegexBufUI_Image.matches(in: S, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: S.characters.count));
if matches.count > 0 {
  for m in 0 ..< matches.count {
    S = S.substring(with: match.rangeAt(m));
```

I get error

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') to expected
>   argument type 'Range'
>   (aka'Range')

I think maybe the reason for the problem is I am now mixing swift datatypes/classes with **NS**.

The mos clean solution here... is that simply casting NSRange to Range? Or is there a way to go fully Swift when I need to use regular expressions as well?

Answer (score 1):

A Swift `Range` and an `NSRange` are different things. It looks like the function is expecting a Swift range which you can create using the `..<` operator. Instead of

```
NSRange(location: 0, length: S.characters.count)
```

write

```
0 ..< S.characters.count
```

Note that the above two things are not identical in semantics although they both represent the same set of characters. The `NSRange` takes the start location and the length of the character sequence. The Swift `Range` uses the lower and upper bound (the upper bound is excluded).

Comment: The problem is I need to use match.rangeAt(m) from the regular expression. Can I convert the result of that somehow, so it can be in the S.substring?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to bridge the string to `NSString`

```
let matches = FRegexBufUI_Image.matches(in: S, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: S.characters.count));
for match in matches { // don't use ugly C-style index based loops
    let substring = (S as NSString).substring(with: match.rangeAt(m))
}
```

---

If you don't want to use mixed types implement this `String` extension which converts `Range<String.Index>` to `NSRange`:

```
extension String {

    func range(from nsRange: NSRange) -> Range<String.Index>? {
        guard
            let from16 = utf16.index(utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: nsRange.location, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex),
            let to16 = utf16.index(from16, offsetBy: nsRange.length, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex),
            let from = String.Index(from16, within: self),
            let to = String.Index(to16, within: self)
            else { return nil }
        return from ..< to
    }

    func substring(withNSRange range : NSRange) -> String
    {
        let swiftRange = self.range(from : range)
        return  swiftRange != nil ? self.substring(with: swiftRange!) : self
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
for match in matches { // don't use ugly C-style index based loops
    let substring = S.substring(withNSRange: match.rangeAt(m))
}
```

**Edit:**

In Swift 4+ the extension has become obsolete. There is a convenience initializer to create `Range<String.Index>` from `NSRange`

```
for match in matches { // don't use ugly C-style index based loops
    let stringRange = Range(match.range(at: m), in: S)!
    let substring = String(S[stringRange])
}
```